# How to access Block reference attributes in pyautocad

Tags: python, autocad

If Bill of Material (BOM) in AutoCAD drawing are in 'Block Reference', to read BOM using pyautocad we can read it using following code.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad

acad = Autocad()
for obj in acad.iter_objects(['Block']):
        if obj.HasAttributes:
            obj.GetAttributes()
```

But it throws exception in
*comtypes\automation.py, line 457, in _get_value typ = _vartype_to_ctype[self.vt & ~VT_ARRAY] KeyError: 9*

How to read BoM in AutoCAD using pyautocad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per issue logged in pyautocad repository, https://github.com/reclosedev/pyautocad/issues/6 comtypes has issue related to accessing array.
Hence to read block references we have to use win32com as follows:

```
import win32com.client
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

# iterate through all objects (entities) in the currently opened drawing
# and if its a BlockReference, display its attributes.
for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace:
    name = entity.EntityName
    if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
        HasAttributes = entity.HasAttributes
        if HasAttributes:
            for attrib in entity.GetAttributes():
                print("  {}: {}".format(attrib.TagString, attrib.TextString))
```

for more details you can see https://gist.github.com/thengineer/7157510.