# Iterate Autocad block attributes on multiple tabs/layouts/paperspaces python

Tags: python, win32com, autocad

I'm trying to print the attributes for blocks on multiple layouts:

```
import win32com.client
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

# iterate through all objects (entities) in the currently opened drawing
# and if its a BlockReference, display its attributes.
for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.PaperSpace:
    name = entity.EntityName
    if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
        HasAttributes = entity.HasAttributes
        if HasAttributes:
            for attrib in entity.GetAttributes():
                print("  {}: {}".format(attrib.TagString, attrib.TextString))
```

Output:

```
  DRAWING-NO: xxxx
  REV: D
  CI-NO_SHORT: 
  CI-NO_LONG: 
  SCALE: NONE
  SHEET: 2
  TOTAL_SHEETS: 17
  CADFILE: xxxx_D.DWG
```

You'll see that it only prints the attributes from the active tab, and not the other 16.

I found out that I need to use win32com and can't use pyautocad for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802416/how-to-access-block-reference-attributes-in-pyautocad). Using pyautocad, I was able to iterate all the layouts, but couldn't get access to the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to Lee’s example
You can also iterate the layouts

```
 acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
    for layout in acad.ActiveDocument.Layouts:
        if layout.ModelType:
            continue
        for ref in layout.Block:
            if ref.EntityName != 'AcDbBlockReference':
                continue
            if not ref.HasAttributes:
                continue
            for attrib in ref.GetAttributes():
                print("  {}: {}".format(attrib.TagString, attrib.TextString))
```

Comment: Good clear example Daniel.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for the example.